# How to convert Promise to async await in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

i am trying to convert different code with promise to async await. as i am new to node and dont have much idea about promise can anybody help me with the following example. my vs code doesn't highlight the promise syntax.

```
module.exports = {
execSqlQuery: function (procedure, parameters) {
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
  var request = new sql.Request(connPool);
  parameters.forEach(function (parameter) {
    request.input(parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value);
  });
  request.execute(procedure, function (err, recordSets) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    else {
      fulfill(recordSets);
    }
  });
});
},
```

Comment: `await` is used to wait for a promise to resolve. In your case, as `request.execute(...)` is callback based, you first need a promise wrapper around `request.execute(...)` and you already have that in the form of `execSqlQuery`. You can `await` the call to `execSqlQuery`: `const data = await execSqlQuery(...)`

Comment: which SQL library are you using because some library support promise approach natively and you don't need to wrap your db execution with promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check whether `request.execute` has a promise version rather than a callback version. If not you can use promisify library to make it a promise.

```
const util = require('util');
const execute= util.promisify(sql.execute); 

const execSqlQuery = async (procedure, parameters) => {     
    var request = new sql.Request(connPool);
    parameters.forEach(function (parameter) {
        request.input(parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value);
      });
    var recordSets = await  request.execute(procedure)
    return recordSets;
}
```

Comment: Or to reduce promise queue processing, `return request.execute(procedure)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you using Microsoft SQL then if it is true: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait

```
function async () {
  var request = new sql.Request(connPool);
  parameters.forEach(function (parameter) {
    request.input(parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value);
  });
  var res = await request.execute(procedure, function (err, recordSets);
  // now check the result for success or errors!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked

```
const execSqlQuery = async (procedure, parameters) => {     
var request = new sql.Request(connPool);
parameters.forEach(function (parameter) {
    request.input(parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value);
  });
var recordSets = await  request.execute(procedure)
return recordSets;
}
```

Comment: Besides answering your own answer, you may accept the answer which helps you to solve the question?